# WindowManager$BadTokenException in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

First of all, I'm well aware that this error is occur because I'm trying to call window/dialog through a `Context` that is not an `Activity`.

But isn't there any solution to that. My requirements are; I have a `Dialog` with a custom style sheet in a method of a normal JAVA class. I want to call that method from any `Activity` class when I need to load the `Dialog`.

In my Activity class I'm having following code set;

```
HomeClass homeClass = new HomeClass();
homeClass.showSplashScreen();
```

Then in my HomeClass I have following code set;

```
public void showSplashScreen() {        
 splashDialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.getAppContext(), R.style.SplashScreen);
 splashDialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
 splashDialog.setCancelable(false);
 splashDialog.show();
}
```

By maintaining this design, is there any way to get rid of the **WindowManager$BadTokenException**

Thank You

Comment: Forgot to mention `getAppContext()` is a static reference to the Activity class. Means there is a code segment like `HomeActivity.homeActivityContext = getApplicationContext();` in my Activity class and from the `getAppContext` it return that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to modify your code, that maybe helpful for you...

```
HomeClass homeClass = new HomeClass(this);
homeClass.showSplashScreen();
```

In Your Home class.. add parametric constructor..

```
public class Home {
private Context context;
public Home(Context context){
this.context = context;
}
public void showSplashScreen() {        
splashDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.SplashScreen);
 splashDialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
 splashDialog.setCancelable(false);
splashDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Your Activity to showSplashScreen() Method...

Do like this..

```
HomeClass homeClass = new HomeClass();
homeClass.showSplashScreen(Your Actvity);
```

In Your Home class

```
public void showSplashScreen(Activity curActivity) {        
 splashDialog = new Dialog(curActivity, R.style.SplashScreen);
 splashDialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
 splashDialog.setCancelable(false);
 splashDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: This is not working. If you are pretty sure about your code, then can you please explain "Your Activity" argument.

Comment: Dude U need to write Your activity name as argument in place of "Your activity"... example: HomeActivity.this

Comment: Yep, I can understand that. But it will give you an Exception. BTW I already figure out a way. Thanks for the reply.